# Применить функцию к списку столбцов датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как применить функцию (например `astype('float64')` не к одному столбцу, а сразу к заданному списку столбцов дата фрейма? Список пусть называется `df_numeric_columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1: передать словарь в качестве аргумента:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1.23', '3.45'], 'col2': ['1.23', '3.45'], 'col3': ['aaa', 'bbb']})
df_numeric_columns = ['col1', 'col2']
df = df.astype({k: 'float64' for k in df_numeric_columns}) # генерируем и передаем словарь в метод; ключ - название столбца, значение - 'float64'
print(df)
```

Вариант 2:

```
df[df_numeric_columns] = df[df_numeric_columns].astype('float64')
```

```
   col1  col2 col3
0  1.23  1.23  aaa
1  3.45  3.45  bbb
```

Comment: А как применить к списку столбцов str. replace?

Comment: Можно с помощью `apply()`: `df[df_numeric_columns] = df[df_numeric_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('1','9'))`